# JDBC not inserting int jdbc table

Tags: java, database, jdbc, error-handling

I am trying to connect java derby db and insert into a table. Everything goes ok but data is not inserted although there is no error at all. Cn you please let me know whats wrong? i tried to change the code and even created new database n table still same. Code works wihtout error but data is not inserted.
Here is my code

databasetest.java

```
package databasetest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DatabaseTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            try{
       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            System.out.println(" class found " );   
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not found driver class" + e);
            };
            try{
            Connection conn = null;
            String pass =null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/user","APP",pass);
            System.out.println(" Connected to database " );   
              try{
                 Statement st;

                 System.out.println(" inserted");

                 conn.close();
              }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(" Eror in inserting" + e );
              }
               }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Mistake happnd  " + e);

               }
}
}
```

here is run result

```
run:
 class found 
 Connected to database 
 inserted
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please can some one tell me whats going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you posted doesn't insert anything. So no wonder the DB doesn't change !

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to reside here: `Statement st;`. You are creating a statement object but you are not associating any queries to it.

Please take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) Oracle Tutorial for more information on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not actually trying to insert anything.

```
Statement st;

System.out.println(" inserted");

conn.close();
```

This doesn't really do anything other than close the connection.

Usually you will want to create a `PreparedStatement` with a query like

```
 PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("place your SQL Query here");
 st.execute();
```

alternatively you could look into the API for `PreparedStatement`.

If you are set on using a regular `Statement` or your query is simple and does not involve insecure input, you can use

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 stmt.execute("Simple SQL Query here");
```

Comment: oh yeah thank you@Dragondraikk for reminding...actually i didnt realise it when i deleted taht statemnt section ...LOL

Answer (score 0):

from the code looks like You have just created the connection with database.

there is no code to insert something into the database.
add the following code to insert some value into your database.

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
String query="Insert into table_name values (comma separated sequential column value)"; //here comes your insertion query
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```